# Airflow DockerOperator cannot find some images but can find others

Tags: image, docker, dockerfile, operators, airflow

I get the following error when trying to use the Docker operator in Airflow. The airflow setup is not visible to me (it is running by another team on a machine I cannot access and the responsible team is not responsive). I created the docker image from a docker file I wrote myself. The name cmprod refers to the docker image.

```
ImageNotFound: 404 Client Error: Not Found ("pull access denied for cmprod, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied")
```

I am unfamiliar with the use of docker login and I am not sure if it applies in this case since I am able to run  some images and not others.
At first I though I incorrectly typed the name of the docker image but I checked and double checked. Below is the output of `docker images`. I was able to run the image condatest successfully through airflow.

```
REPOSITORY               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
cm_prod                  latest              08f408557eb7        15 hours ago        2.12GB
cmprod                   latest              08f408557eb7        15 hours ago        2.12GB
<none>                   <none>              4af8c991ea19        15 hours ago        730MB
<none>                   <none>              9da4759a3316        15 hours ago        64.2MB
condatest                latest              e24563f9bb48        5 days ago          2.12GB
```

I thought I might be using the docker operator incorrectly but I am able to run some other images. I thought maybe there was an airflow configuration issue where certain operating systems were not allowed or running with certain permissions was not allowed but I have been unable to find any documentation on whether this is possible.

My testing does not show any of the above factors to determine 100% whether a docker image can or cannot be found by airflow using the docker operator. This problem does not seem amenable to trial and error. Any advice on what may be happening would be appreciated.

I am able to see the airflow UI in my browser and trigger dags and there is a shared directory where I can dump my dag specification script. Airflow is Version : 1.10.3.

The version info for docker follows `docker version`:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.6
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.16
 Git commit:        369ce74a3c
 Built:             Thu Feb 13 01:29:29 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.6
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.16
  Git commit:       369ce74a3c
  Built:            Thu Feb 13 01:28:07 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

EDIT:
The airflow DAG code was requested. I am hesitant to post the whole thing because I inherited some code from a team member who left and I feel like some of the code in the dag would be best implemented as a separate script. Below are the most relevant code blocks. Let me know if anything seems missing. There is a section between these blocks I omit for clarity but can include if nothing seems to work.

CODE BLOCK 1: Import dependencies

```py
from functools import reduce
import os, os.path
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.mssql_operator import MsSqlOperator
from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator
from airflow.utils.helpers import chain
```

CODE BLOCK 2: DAG and OPERATOR Instantiation

```py
# create SQL operators
def create_SQL_operator(taskfile, dag):
    """
    Creates a MsSQL operator for a given DAG.
    """
    op = MsSqlOperator(
        task_id=taskfile,
        sql=readSQL(os.path.join(ProjDir, taskfile)),
        mssql_conn_id='clarity',
        autocommit=True,
        database='clarity',
        dag=dag
        )
    return op

# Airflow arguments
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'description': 'Parallel SQL DAG',
    'depend_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 1),
    'email': ['*PERSONTOEMAIL*'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': True
}

# DAG definition
DAG = DAG(ProjName + '_and_infer',
          description='Running parallel SQLs for project: {} and inference on the data'.format(ProjName),
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval=CronTime,   # '0 */2 * * *',  #every 2 hours
          concurrency=50,               # setup to allow 50 concurrent parallel tasks
          catchup=False)
t_predict = DockerOperator(
        task_id='dockerPredict',
        image='cmprod',
        api_version='auto',
        auto_remove=True,
        volumes=['*ABSOLUTEPATHTOMOUNT*:/ds-cm'],
        command='bash inference.sh ',
        docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',
        network_mode='bridge',
        dag=DAG)

# Create SQL task operators in Airflow global space
ops = []
ops = [(order, create_SQL_operator(taskfile, DAG)) for order, taskfile in sql_rank]
ops.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0])

# create cluster ops list
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
opsList = []
opsList = [[j for i, j in grouper] for order, grouper in groupby(ops, key=itemgetter(0))]

# flatten list with only 1 element: Airflow chain() cannot accept list of lists!!
chainList = []
chainList = [reduce(plus, list) if len(list) == 1 else list for list in opsList]
chainList.append(t_predict)

# create final DAG graph
exec(r' >> '.join([r'chainList['+str(i)+r']' for i in range(len(chainList))]))
```

UPDATE
Since I originally posted this question I substituted the condatest image into the above code and managed to error out in a different way: there was a missing shell script in the mounted directory.

When I copied the missing file and ran again airflow could no longer find the condatest image. I checked and saw that the newly copied script did not have execute permission and added the permission. Airflow still could not find the previously working docker container.

I deleted the shell script and airflow can find the container again. Does this mean the problem has to do with Linux permissions? It is unclear to me how the contents of the mounted drive affect the ability of airflow to detect the container. Furthermore, I know I was able to run that same script using a docker container started by a dockerobject in airflow in the past.

Comment: Can you paste your DAG code ? I need to check the code to debug further. Thanks.

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon I added most of the code. There was some other stuff having to do with administering the SQL code for the job that I left out to try to make the dag code clearer. Let me know if you want me to post the whole thing.

Comment: can you run the docker container from the box(instance where airflow is running becoming that user that runs airflow ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have login credentials to that machine. The best I can do is run a dag that is stripped down to just the Docker operator. I was able to get the condatest image discussed in the update to work in that manner. Do you have suggestions I can pass along to the team that owns that machine? I will have to wait a few days for them to get around to it.

Comment: On further investigation airflow is running on the same machine I am doing my development, I just don't have permissions to run airflow from the command line or access the directories where the files are stored. So I can run the container just fine. Airflow is executing as root as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading airflow to airflow2 the logs have provided some additional information. Airflow had been configured to run on multiple servers and docker had been set up on each server but no image registry had been used. It seems that when the job scheduler tried to execute the dag on a server other than the server where I built my docker image the image was unavailable. It seems the workarounds I was finding earlier were just coincided with a lucky draw for what server my job was scheduled on.

To resolve this we have configured our scheduler to use only one server.