# Docker cannot find image if shell script is in mounted directory when using airflow bash operator

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, airflow

While doing follow up investigations on the stackoverflow question:
[Airflow DockerOperator cannot find some images but can find others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63363716/airflow-dockeroperator-cannot-find-some-images-but-can-find-others). I tried loading a docker image using an airflow bash operator replicating exactly how I run it from my terminal and it gave me the same error.

Below is an easily reproducible test case. I am running docker and airflow on a CentOS system.

When I try this from my terminal:

```
docker run -mount type=bind,source=\host\path,target=\mount\path image_name ls
```

The output looks like:

```
PythonSource
SQLSource
data
inference.sh
```

When I do the same from an airflow bash operator the output looks like:

```
[2020-08-18 13:20:29,565] {bash_operator.py:114} INFO - Running command: docker run --mount type=bind,source=/host/path,target=/mount/path perm_test ls /mount/path 
[2020-08-18 13:20:29,570] {bash_operator.py:123} INFO - Output:
[2020-08-18 13:20:29,627] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO - Unable to find image 'image_name:latest' locally
[2020-08-18 13:20:30,105] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO - docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for perm_test, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```

An interesting thing happens if I remove the shell script (`rm \host\path\*.sh`) and trigger the airflow dag with the same command. The output looks like:

```
[2020-08-18 13:26:59,620] {bash_operator.py:123} INFO - Output:
[2020-08-18 13:27:00,355] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO - PythonSource
[2020-08-18 13:27:00,355] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO - SQLSource
[2020-08-18 13:27:00,356] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO - data
```

Right now it seems like there is an airflow security setting that is preventing me from doing anything in the mounted directory if there is a shell script present. It is not critical that the shell script be present but the way the operation fails (i.e. messaging that docker cannot find the container and looking for it in a repo) was very misleading. I am going to be using this airflow system frequently in the future and am worried I will run into similar problems. I am unsure as to whether this is an airflow issue or an OS admin issue.

1. Why is this happening?
2. Is there a certain class of commands that can be done from the command line normally cannot be executed by airflow?
3. Is there some way to configure airflow (or CentOS) to be compatible with mounting directories that contain shell scripts?

It makes it very hard to develop when things that normally work perfectly fine break when you put them into a task scheduler and none of the errors make any sense.

Comment: what does inference.sh do ?

Comment: Not much some admin stuff change directory activate conda environment etc. I just wrote it so I didn't have to keep track of the directories and the conda environment name during testing. It is important to note in the above example *the shell script never runs*. Its presence in the directory is the problem not its function.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to airflow2 I was able to see what server the scheduler assigned my job in the task logs. It seems the that it was merely coincidence that the presence or absence of the shell script cooccurred with success or failure of the job. The real problem was that the scheduler was configured to run the job on a server that did not have the image built on it.

The solution was to configure airflow to run on a single server.

Answer (score 0):

Verify your image existence using **docker image ls** .
As i can check the image_name is set as perm_test in:

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source=/host/path,target=/mount/path perm_test ls /mount/path
```

And the error `Unable to find image 'image_name:latest' locally` occurred.

There is high chance of typographical error  or Misspell. Please verify your image name.

Comment: See the problem description as you can see the image is running when I remove the shell script. If it was a typo I would still not be able to find it. Please read the question before answering.